# FluxCD sync application from AWS Codecommit not work

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, flux, aws-codecommit

I create a AWS codecommit repository that use for flux sync application but sync failed.
The deployment.yaml I create did not produce pods in EKS as I expected.

But in the flux log that looks great.

```
...
2022-03-02T08:20:56.336Z info GitRepository/flux-system.flux-system - Reconciliation finished in 3.605422284s, next run in 1m0s 
2022-03-02T08:22:00.082Z info GitRepository/flux-system.flux-system - Reconciliation finished in 3.745400563s, next run in 1m0s 
2022-03-02T08:23:03.845Z info GitRepository/flux-system.flux-system - Reconciliation finished in 3.762569909s, next run in 1m0s 
...
```

Not sure how to check for errors.

The depolyment.yaml context following:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-hostname-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 80
```

The file tree in codecommit repository like:

```
└── clusters
    └── my-cluster
        ├── demo
        │   └── nginx.yaml
        └── flux-system
            ├── gotk-components.yaml
            ├── gotk-sync.yaml
            └── kustomization.yaml
```

Flux check command

```
► checking prerequisites
✔ Kubernetes 1.20.11-eks-f17b81 >=1.20.6-0
► checking controllers
✔ helm-controller: deployment ready
► ghcr.io/fluxcd/helm-controller:v0.17.1
✔ kustomize-controller: deployment ready
► ghcr.io/fluxcd/kustomize-controller:v0.21.1
✔ notification-controller: deployment ready
► ghcr.io/fluxcd/notification-controller:v0.22.2
✔ source-controller: deployment ready
► ghcr.io/fluxcd/source-controller:v0.21.2
✔ all checks passed
```

Flux pods status:

```
NAMESPACE   NAME                        READY   MESSAGE                         REVISION        SUSPENDED 
flux-system gitrepository/flux-system   True    Fetched revision: main/cc31370  main/cc31370    False       

NAMESPACE   NAME                        READY   MESSAGE                         REVISION        SUSPENDED 
flux-system kustomization/flux-system   True    Applied revision: main/cc31370  main/cc31370    False
```

It's looks all good, But not as expected that deployed pods in EKS.

#### Environment

1. flux   version 0.27.3
2. k8s    version 1.20.0
3. eksctl version 0.84.0
4. OS.    Amazon-Linux

If any other info is needed, I'll add it right away, just hope that the cause of the error can be found

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your nginx deployment is NOT part of cluster reconciliation. Use `kustomize build cluster/my-cluster/flux-system` locally to see if the deployment is here or not.

See [example](https://github.com/fluxcd/flux2-kustomize-helm-example/blob/main/clusters/staging/infrastructure.yaml#L11) how include additional conf in that cluster.